# Use VBA to make Excel refresh data from source

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel sheet contains a table which fetches data from an outside source. I know I can refresh this data by right clicking the table and clicking "Refresh", but I want to be able to do this from inside my VBA code, so that I can force the data to be updated before performing certain calculations on it.

I have tried using `Worksheets("Foo").Calculate` as suggested by answers to similar questions, but that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Try to record a macro and do the "Refresh". It's the best option for something like this.

Comment: +1 for `record a macro`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to use `QueryTable("tableName").Refresh`.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174288%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is the link to the Microsoft Developer Network page on Query Table.  Check out the refresh method from there.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but VBA can't seem to find my table by its name. That seems to be a different problem though.

Comment: If its your only table, you should be able to use QueryTable(1). If you have a lot of tables, finding its index number may be harder and you might be better off recording a macro as was suggested in the question comments.

Comment: `Worksheets("Foo").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` seemed to be the way to find my table. Strangely it wasn't even listed in `QueryTable()`.